# Meaning of "two out of three ain't bad"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In this song's lyrics, I cannot understand the phrase "two out of three ain't bad" :

> ...
>   I want you, I need you
>   But there ain't no way I'm ever gonna love you
>   Now don't be sad
>   'Cause ***two out of three ain't bad***.
>   ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. I want you.
2. I need you.
3. <strike>I love you.</strike>

That's two out of three. Which is better than one out of three, or even zero out of three. So, according to the author, the person whom the song is dedicated to shouldn't be sad that they are not being loved. It could be worse.

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers. Too little sleep makes Reg stoopid.

Comment: A rare lapse indeed. Me I think there should be a special EL&U badge for successfully editing one of *your* answers! :)